# How would one select an element with the class="" using jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

The text I want to select using the class="" is shown below:

```
<span class="">1&nbsp;Comment</span>
```

$('.').each(function(i,elem)... does not seem to work.

I also want to parse the text so I get the integer value not just the string text "1".

Thanks

Comment: is your class name empty ?

Comment: @Pete, there is a difference between not having a class attribute, and having a class attribute that is empty.

Comment: For the bolted-on, 2-questions-for-the-price-of-1, second part, you can multiply by 1 : `var x = val * 1;` then x is a number or 0 if val is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select elements that have an attribute with a specific value. The value happens to be the empty string.

Use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[class=""]')
```